# UITextView Delegate is not firing shouldChangeTextInrange delegate method

Tags: ios, swift, delegates, uitextview, uitextviewdelegate

I have a `UITextView` connected from Storyboard, call it `txtView`. In my `ViewController` I set the delegate like `txtView.delegate = self`.

The view controller fires method like `textViewDidBeginEditing` and `textViewDidChange`, but not `func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextIn range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool`

Yes, I did set the `delegate` in my view controller.

Yes, I did put `UITextViewDelegate`in my class declaration

No, I did not confuse `UITextView` with `UITextField`.

Any idea? Thanks!

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextViewDelegate, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {
  @IBOutlet weak var txtView: UITextView!

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    txtView.delegate = self
    txtView.becomeFirstResponder()  
    txtView.text = "txt"
  }

  func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) {
    print("THIS PRINTS")
  }

  func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextIn range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool {
    print("WHY DOESN'T THIS GET CALLED?")
    return true
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you paste your code?

Comment: Done. It never calls the second delegate method...

Comment: With exactly the same code, the second delegate is called. (I get "WHY DOESN'T THIS GET CALLED?" in Xcode console.) Can you reproduce the same issue with exactly the same code you have shown? Something hidden may be affecting.